# Graphics cards that work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, hardware, amd-graphics

I've recently embarked on a PC building project, I've got some of the components sorted out (well, the CPU!) and I'm trying to look for a graphics card to buy.

I've been spending the past hour or so trawling reviews, specs, and prices for various different graphics cards . . . and to be honest I could probably do this all day without coming to a good conclusion!

The problem is, the CPU I've decided on is an AMD CPU, as far as I know this restricts me to AMD graphics (please correct me if I'm wrong here) so I've been looking at AMD graphics cards, I've found various cards that seem like what I want, but I'm having real difficulty trying to ascertain whether or not they're compatible with Linux.

Wherever I go I seem to get conflicting information, all I can really conclude is that Intel has good driver support for Linux. However as far as I know, their cards are a little underpowered, and I'd also need an Intel Motherboard and CPU for that to work? A lot of places also seem to say that AMD support for Linux isn't nearly as good as it could be?

**Does anybody know of any good linux compatible AMD graphics cards that I can buy? Or should I rethink and go for an intel/NVIDIA card?**

**I'm not looking for anything very flashy, just something that plays HD video and could handle simple games like Minecraft to a decent degree.**

I also browsed around here a little too, apparently [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sapphire-11166-02-20R-5450-DDR3-Graphics/dp/B0036DD4CO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337533870&sr=8-1) is a good card for Ubuntu? Although searching online people complain of problem with that card and Ubuntu? This is so confusing!!!

Hope there aren't too many question marks there!

edit: not sure if this is relevant for drivers, but I'm also looking for a dual monitor setup - does that impact this in any way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NVIDIA cards on an AMD platform... the only difficulty you'll have would be with Crossfire (which, I believe, you can fix with BIOS patches).

YMMV as far as drivers; all of them seem to work fine for most users, with the exception of the proprietary AMD Catalyst (fglrx) drivers, which are a constant source of heartache and pain.